# How to change python to .exe file in visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, exe

How to change python code to **.exe** file using microsoft Visual Studio 2015 without installing any package? Under "Build" button, there is no convert to **.exe** file.

Comment: You say you do t want a package, but this is necessary. Try `py2exe` (it’s a utility, not a package). There are others too. Answer by user Access Denied is correct on why you cannot do this in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Python is a dynamic language (executed by interpreter) and cannot be compiled to binary. (Similar to javascript, php and etc.) It needs interpreter to execute python commands. It's not possible to do that without 3rd party tools which translates python to another languages and compile them to exe.

Comment: I can run python code in visual studio but cannot change to .exe file, if run in C# then can change to exe file

Comment: Please, take a look at the following article: http://www.programiz.com/article/difference-compiler-interpreter

Comment: C# has a compiler which compiles code to IL, translated to machine commands by JIT compiler at runtime. That's why you see compiled exe. Python code is not compiled, but interpreted (code is analyzed and machine instruction are executed) on the fly at runtime, without compilation progress.

Answer (score 2):

As said in this thread you in contrast to C# there is no .exe file in the folder. You will need to make one yourself. I am using pyinstaller, which is easy to use. Read how to use here: [Pyinstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). My favourite attributes are -F(one file executable) and for GUI apps --noconsole(won't show console when the app is running).